# Trouble with clang_complete, no error and loaded but does not work

Tags: c++, vim, vim-plugin, clang-complete

I am trying to use `clang_complete` for `vim` on Arch Linux. I built `vim` and `vimball` plugin from source. I see `+python/dyn` and `+python3/dyn` in `vim --version` output. I use the following `.vimrc` file :

```
syntax on
filetype plugin on
let g:clang_complete_copen=1
let g:clang_complete_auto=0
let g:clang_user_options='|| exit 0'
let g:clang_use_library=1
let g:clang_library_path='/usr/lib/libclang.so'
```

In `:scriptnames`, I see `~/.vimrc/plugin/clang_complete.vim` is loaded.

Overall, it does not work! If I open a `C++` file then `vim` shows incorrect UI behaviour without reporting any error. e.g. cursor is invisible, typing words takes place in wrong positions, no syntax highlight, ... . The cursor remains invisible even after quit.

I think `clang` library can be loaded since any change in the path makes an error.

Is there any mistake in the above settings?

Comment: I take it that if you remove the plugin, `vim` behavior goes back to normal? For what it's worth, I've been happily using https://github.com/justmao945/vim-clang for a few months now with no complaints.

Comment: @JoelCornett Yes, the problem will be gone if I remove clang_complete. thanks for your suggestion :) . Which features of clang_complete are not in vim-clang?

Comment: You issue is probably related to [this](https://github.com/Rip-Rip/clang_complete/issues/453). It's a bug in `libclang`, here is open [ticket](https://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=25007) in their bug tracker.

Comment: Have you tried with just one version of Python? I just resolved this issue, albeit in Debian. If you'd like to use Python3, try myint/clang_complete.